# How do I wrap up a Ruby C extension in a Ruby Gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I can't find many docs on this. How do I package a gem such that the C extension is compiled when the gem is installed?

In particular I want to do this:

- on Linux and MacOSX i would like compile the C extension on gem install
- on Windows I would like to simply install a precompiled .so

any help on this, in particular example source, would be very useful :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Luis Lavena](http://Blog.MMediaSys.Com/) has created [`rake-compiler`](https://github.com/rake-compiler/rake-compiler) just for this purpose.

- [Homepage / GitHub](https://github.com/rake-compiler/rake-compiler)
- [GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/rake-compiler/rake-compiler/wiki)

However, are you sure that you need a C extension? The thing about C extensions is that every Ruby implementation has their own C extension API (and non-C based ones like XRuby, JRuby, Ruby.NET, IronRuby, HotRuby, MagLev, Red Sun don't have one at all), which means that your C extension will only work on *one* implementation. And, since MRI *only* implements Ruby 1.8 and YARV *only* implements Ruby 1.9, and we are currently in a transition phase between 1.8 and 1.9, chances are that a lot of people will use at least two different implementations. (I personally use 5: MRI, YARV, JRuby, IronRuby and Rubinius.)

Maybe you are better off using [Ruby-FFI](https://Wiki.GitHub.Com/FFI/FFI/). Ruby-FFI is an FFI (Foreign Function Interface) for Ruby (*duh*), which allows you to bind to and map C libraries in pure Ruby in a manner that is portable across Ruby implementations. The FFI API was first developed by [Evan Phoenix](http://Blog.FallingSnow.Net/) as the native extension API for [Rubinius](http://Rubini.us/), it was then adopted by [Charles Oliver Nutter](http://Blog.Headius.Com/) (and implemented by [Wayne Meissner](http://WMeissner.BlogSpot.Com/)) for [JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/). [Wayne](http://WMeissner.BlogSpot.Com/) then also wrote the [Ruby-FFI gem](https://Wiki.GitHub.Com/FFI/FFI/), which contains C extensions for MRI and YARV. [Laurent Sansonetti](http://MacRuby.Org/blog/) implemented Ruby-FFI for [MacRuby](http://MacRuby.Org/), [Marc-André Cournoyer](http://MACournoyer.Com/)'s [tinyrb](http://Code.MACournoyer.Com/tinyrb/) also [supports FFI](https://GitHub.Com/WMeissner/TinyRb/) (again written by [Wayne Meissner](http://WMeissner.BlogSpot.Com/)) and the [MagLev](http://MagLev.GemStone.Com/) developers are also working on it. Which means that if you can make your library work with FFI as opposed to a C extension, you will automatically support 6 Ruby implementations instead of just one.

The only reason to use a C extension as opposed to an FFI extension would be, if you really *do* want some implementation specific behavior. One example of this would be the [ParseTree](http://ParseTree.RubyForge.Org/) gem, which reaches deep into the intestines of MRI and rips out the in-memory representation of the parse tree.

Last but not least, take a look at the [Nice-FFI](https://github.com/jacius/nice-ffi/) project by [John Croisant](http://Blog.Jacius.Info/), which aims to make using [Ruby-FFI](https://Wiki.GitHub.Com/FFI/FFI/) even nicer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a github repo that I maintain just for my own reference and these things have helped me.

[Ruby_C_extensions](https://github.com/DouglasAllen/Ruby_C_extensions)

It may help to look around on github to find some good examples of gems already written just for your study but go ahead and clone them and see if you can build them on your system. If they were put together right they should build just fine.

Please note that you do need some build tools in any platform you're using. Here is a video that I just watched that tells you what you need for Linux.

[Python Programming Environment Setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxaqsgrYkh4)

Now I know that that it says Python, he does show you how to install the build tools packages.

I use DevKit for Windows and it works for me. With anything the installation of the tools is the most important.

I also have used rake-compiler and hoe to set up the folder structure. So it looks like we have to lean some gardening by getting a rake and a hoe. :-D