# While executing gem ... ["extconf.rb", ...] are not files

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

I'm trying to build a ruby gem around a C extension. The C extension compiles fine using the `ruby extconf.rb; make; sudo make install` routine, but when I try to build a gem using rake, the process terminates with the error at the bottom of this trace.

I'm using the post [here](http://writehack.com/2011/1/30/Packaging%20a%20Ruby%20C%20Extension%20as%20a%20Gem), with the same directory structure, to create the gem.

What's wrong with my configuration? My gemspec and Rakefile are below the trace (the gem is called netconf).

// Trace

```
** Execute copy:netconf:i686-linux:1.9.2
install -c tmp/i686-linux/netconf/1.9.2/netconf.so lib/netconf/netconf.so
** Execute compile:netconf:i686-linux
** Execute compile:i686-linux
** Execute compile
** Invoke chmod (first_time)
** Execute chmod
** Execute build
rake aborted!
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InvalidSpecificationException)
    ["extconf.rb", "netconf.o", "netconf.so"] are not files
```

// netconf.gemspec

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
require "netconf/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "netconf"
  s.version     = Netconf::VERSION
  s.authors     = ["..."]
  s.email       = ["..."]
  s.homepage    = "..."
  s.summary     = %q{A tool to access and write Ubuntu network configuration}
  s.description = %q{Uses ifconfig and other C system calls to access network configurations on a Ubuntu install.}

  s.rubyforge_project = "netconf"

  s.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
  s.executables   = `git ls-files -- bin/*`.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
  s.require_paths = ["lib"]
  s.extensions    = ["ext/netconf/extconf.rb"]
end
```

// Rakefile

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/extensiontask'
require 'bundler'

Rake::ExtensionTask.new("netconf") do |extension|
  extension.lib_dir = "lib/netconf"
end

task :chmod do
  File.chmod(0775, 'lib/netconf/netconf.so')
end

task :build => [:clean, :compile, :chmod]

Bundler::GemHelper.install_tasks
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314827/how-do-i-wrap-up-a-ruby-c-extension-in-a-ruby-gem) may be relevant

Comment: I saw that question; thanks for the head's up though. I'm using rake-compiler, but I haven't been able to find any information on this particular error (and I'm pretty sure that I need/want a native C extension since I'm targeting a single embedded platform).

Answer (score 51):

I got this error because I hadn't commited my updates with git yet.

```
s.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
```

That line is directly using git, and probably causing this error. Just do

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "init"
```

Comment: thank you for sharing this, you have saved me a lot of headache. having the files staged (not necessarily committed was all that was needed for me ^ _ ^ )

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I had a similar issue where

```
s.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
```

was

```
s.files         = `git ls-files`.split('\n')
```

, where the single quotes were preventing the file list from splitting properly.  Changing to double quotes fixed the issue for me.