# How do I wrap a compiled command line tool for use in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, bash, sip, pjsip

I have compiled and tested an open-source command line SIP client for my machine which we can assume has the same architecture as all other machines in our shop. By this I mean that I have successfully passed a compiled binary to others in the shop and they were able to use them.

The tool has a fairly esoteric invocation, a simple bash script piped to it prior to execution as follows:

```
(sleep 3; echo "# 1"; sleep 3; echo h) | pjsua sip:somephonenumber@ip --flag_1 val --flag_2 val
```

Note that the leading bash script is an essential part of the functioning of the program and that the line itself seems to be the best practice for use.

In the framing of my problem I am considering the following:

1. I don't think I can expect very many others in the shop to
   compile the binary for themselves
2. Having a common system architecture in the shop it is reasonable to think that a repo can house the most up-to-date version
3. Having a way to invoke the tool using Ruby would be the most useful and the most accessible to the
   most people.
4. The leading bash script being passed needs to be wholly extensible. These signify modifiable "scenarios" e.g. in this case:

   1. Call
   2. Wait three seconds
   3. Press 1
   4. Wait three seconds
   5. Hang up
5. There may be as many as a dozen flags. Possibly a configuration file.

Is it a reasonable practice to create a gem that carries at its core a command line tool that has been previously compiled?

Comment: [rhodes](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes) is a framework that appears to include compiled versions of the software for several different platform architectures.

Comment: [redis-rb](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) would seem to necessitate installing redis independently and prior to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like the vocabulary I was missing is extension. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314827/how-do-i-wrap-up-a-ruby-c-extension-in-a-ruby-gem) is a great stack discussion on wrapping up a Ruby C extension in a Ruby Gem.

Here is a [link](http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/) to the Gem Guides on creating Gems with Extensions.

Apparently not only is it done but there are sets of best practices around its use.

Answer (score 1):

It seems reasonable to create a gem that uses a command line tool. The only thing I'd say is to check that the command is available using `system('which psjua')` and raising an informative error if it hasn't been installed.

Comment: Sorry I have modified the question for clarity. The leading bash script i.e. `(sleep 3; echo "# 1"; sleep 3; echo h)` needs to be extensible as well. There may be as many as a dozen flags and possibly even config files (which all the rubists would prefer to be .yml files).

Comment: Ah, so then my second suggestion seems like the way to go. Make a module that uses `system()` and pulls in options from the .yml file.

Comment: It's a reasonable suggestion but by nature this product to be shared is very complex. The question is not "what is the easiest way to do this?". The question is "Is it a reasonable practice to create a gem that carries at its core a command line tool that has been previously compiled?"